Issue with Removing MySQL Server Package
I'm encountering difficulties removing the mysql-server-8.0 package from my server. Every attempt to remove it results in an error indicating that the package is in a very bad inconsistent state. The specific error message is:
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

This issue arose as I was attempting to manually download WordPress onto my server. I suspect there might be some conflict or inconsistency causing this problem. Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
when i try
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*

i get
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysql-source-8.0' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysqltcl' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-8.0' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-router' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-8.0' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-sandbox' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-8.0' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-testsuite-8.0' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysqltuner' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.5' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.6' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-5.7' for glob 'mysql*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-server-core-8.0' for glob 'mysql*'
Package 'mysql-client-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'mysql-common' instead of 'mysql-common-5.6'
Package 'mysql-server-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-core-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite-5.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-sandbox' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysqltcl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysqltuner' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-client' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-router' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-source-8.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mysql-testsuite-8.0' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libdbi-perl libencode-locale-perl
  libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl
  libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl
  libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmecab2
  libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libdbd-mysql-perl* libmysqlclient21* mariadb-common* mysql-client-8.0*
  mysql-client-core-8.0* mysql-common* mysql-server-8.0*
  mysql-server-core-8.0*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 8 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 267 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
azureuser@Assignment1And2:~$ 

Thank you!

Have you tried to reinstall the mentioned package ? Something  like ˝sudo apt install --reintall mysql-server-8.0˝ and, if that succeeds, run the remove again,

@SorenA when i try to install it, 'Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.36-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
new mysql-server-8.0 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1' sorry not enough room to post whole error

The error you got, says that there are an instance of Mysql running that can't be stopped. Stop/kill it, clean up old locks, and try again.

@SorenA when i try "sudo systemctl stop mysql"
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded. when i try "sudo killall -9 mysqld mysqld_safe" mysqld: no process found
mysqld_safe: no process found

Can you edit your question and the the result of: ps -A | grep mysql. Please also add your Ubuntu version. Based on what you shared so far, I am guessing you are using Ubuntu 20.04, can you confirm this?

@sotirov I can confirm that is the version, the command doesn't output anything :(
